# Maggento2 how to create new cms page

Tags: cms-pages

Magento2.4.2 community version create multi-site multi-store multi-view situation, add CMS page in the background, how to remove the head and tail of the code, and how to add custom CSS files and JS files

Answer (score 0):

Create New store under store > Setting >all stores ,

Then , go to content > design > configuration, edit you store , add theme, header,footer, add custome css and js. Save it .